# There is already an object named 'dbUser' in the database

Tags: javascript, sql-server

I'm trying to upload my database from local to hosting. I'm using Server 2008 and hosting using 2012. When I upload my database I recieve this error:

**" There is already an object named 'dbUser' in the database. "**

How can I solve this problem?

```html
USE [phanthi3_db]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[dbUser]    Script Date: 01/04/2017 15:20:31 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dbUser](
 [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Type] [int] NULL,
 [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [UserName] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [Pass] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [Status] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbUser] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[dbUser] ON
INSERT [dbo].[dbUser] ([ID], [Type], [Name], [UserName], [Pass], [Status]) VALUES (1, 1, N'namlinhvn', N'namlinhvn', N'E10ADC3949BA59ABBE56E057F20F883E', 1)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[dbUser] OFF
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[dbNewsType]    Script Date: 01/04/2017 15:20:31 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dbNewsType](
 [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
 [ImageURL] [varchar](50) NULL,
 [Status] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [ViewCount] [int] NULL,
 [SEOName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
 [OderBy] [int] NULL,
 [IsIndex] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbNewsType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] ON
INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] ([ID], [Name], [ImageURL], [Status], [ViewCount], [SEOName], [OderBy], [IsIndex]) VALUES (1, N'Công nghệ', N'', 1, 0, N'0', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] ([ID], [Name], [ImageURL], [Status], [ViewCount], [SEOName], [OderBy], [IsIndex]) VALUES (2, N'Đời sống', N'', 1, 0, N'0', 2, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] ([ID], [Name], [ImageURL], [Status], [ViewCount], [SEOName], [OderBy], [IsIndex]) VALUES (4, N'Khám phá', N'', 1, 0, N'', 0, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] ([ID], [Name], [ImageURL], [Status], [ViewCount], [SEOName], [OderBy], [IsIndex]) VALUES (5, N'Mẹo vặt', N' ', 1, 0, N'0', 0, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] ([ID], [Name], [ImageURL], [Status], [ViewCount], [SEOName], [OderBy], [IsIndex]) VALUES (6, N'Video nổi bật', N' ', 1, 0, N'0', 0, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] ([ID], [Name], [ImageURL], [Status], [ViewCount], [SEOName], [OderBy], [IsIndex]) VALUES (7, N'Hàng xách tay Úc', N' ', 1, 0, N'0', 0, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] ([ID], [Name], [ImageURL], [Status], [ViewCount], [SEOName], [OderBy], [IsIndex]) VALUES (8, N'Công nghệ mới', N' ', 1, 0, N'0', 1, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] ([ID], [Name], [ImageURL], [Status], [ViewCount], [SEOName], [OderBy], [IsIndex]) VALUES (9, N'Khoa học', N'', 1, 0, N'', 0, 0)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] OFF
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[dbNewsDictionary]    Script Date: 01/04/2017 15:20:31 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dbNewsDictionary](
 [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
 [Subject] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [MainContent] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [SEOsubject] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbNewsDictionary_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

and get error like this:

```html
Changed database context to 'phanthi3_db'.

Changed database context to 'phanthi3_db'.

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dbUser]( 
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
[Type] [int] NULL, 
[Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
[UserName] [varchar](50) NULL, 
[Pass] [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
[Status] [bit] NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbUser] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( 
[ID] ASC 
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] 
) ON [PRIMARY]
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line number 1
There is already an object named 'dbUser' in the database.

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[dbUser] ON 
INSERT [dbo].[dbUser] ([ID], [Type], [Name], [UserName], [Pass], [Status]) VALUES (1, 1, N'namlinhvn', N'namlinhvn', N'E10ADC3949BA59ABBE56E057F20F883E', 1) 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[dbUser] OFF 
/****** Object: Table [dbo].[dbNewsType] Script Date: 01/04/2017 15:20:31 ******/ 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line number 2
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbUser'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.dbUser'. The duplicate key value is (1).

Msg 3621, Level 0, State 0, Line number 2
The statement has been terminated.

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dbNewsType]( 
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
[Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL, 
[ImageURL] [varchar](50) NULL, 
[Status] [bit] NOT NULL, 
[ViewCount] [int] NULL, 
[SEOName] [nvarchar](100) NULL, 
[OderBy] [int] NULL, 
[IsIndex] [bit] NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbNewsType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( 
[ID] ASC 
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY] 
) ON [PRIMARY]
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line number 1
There is already an object named 'dbNewsType' in the database.

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] ON 
INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] ([ID], [Name], [ImageURL], [Status], [ViewCount], [SEOName], [OderBy], [IsIndex]) VALUES (1, N'Công nghệ', N'', 1, 0, N'0', 1, 1) 
INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] ([ID], [Name], [ImageURL], [Status], [ViewCount], [SEOName], [OderBy], [IsIndex]) VALUES (2, N'Đời sống', N'', 1, 0, N'0', 2, 1) 
INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] ([ID], [Name], [ImageURL], [Status], [ViewCount], [SEOName], [OderBy], [IsIndex]) VALUES (4, N'Khám phá', N'', 1, 0, N'', 0, 1) 
INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] ([ID], [Name], [ImageURL], [Status], [ViewCount], [SEOName], [OderBy], [IsIndex]) VALUES (5, N'Mẹo vặt', N' ', 1, 0, N'0', 0, 1) 
INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] ([ID], [Name], [ImageURL], [Status], [ViewCount], [SEOName], [OderBy], [IsIndex]) VALUES (6, N'Video nổi bật', N' ', 1, 0, N'0', 0, 1) 
INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] ([ID], [Name], [ImageURL], [Status], [ViewCount], [SEOName], [OderBy], [IsIndex]) VALUES (7, N'Hàng xách tay Úc', N' ', 1, 0, N'0', 0, 1) 
INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] ([ID], [Name], [ImageURL], [Status], [ViewCount], [SEOName], [OderBy], [IsIndex]) VALUES (8, N'Công nghệ mới', N' ', 1, 0, N'0', 1, 0) 
INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] ([ID], [Name], [ImageURL], [Status], [ViewCount], [SEOName], [OderBy], [IsIndex]) VALUES (9, N'Khoa học', N'', 1, 0, N'', 0, 0) 
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[dbNewsType] OFF 
/****** Object: Table [dbo].[dbNewsDictionary] Script Date: 01/04/2017 15:20:31 ******/ 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line number 2
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbNewsType'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.dbNewsType'. The duplicate key value is (1).

Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line number 3
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbNewsType'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.dbNewsType'. The duplicate key value is (2).

Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line number 4
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbNewsType'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.dbNewsType'. The duplicate key value is (4).

Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line number 5
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbNewsType'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.dbNewsType'. The duplicate key value is (5).

Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line number 6
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbNewsType'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.dbNewsType'. The duplicate key value is (6).

Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line number 7
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbNewsType'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.dbNewsType'. The duplicate key value is (7).

Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line number 8
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbNewsType'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.dbNewsType'. The duplicate key value is (8).

Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line number 9
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbNewsType'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.dbNewsType'. The duplicate key value is (9).

Msg 3621, Level 0, State 0, Line number 2
The statement has been terminated.

Msg 3621, Level 0, State 0, Line number 3
The statement has been terminated.

Msg 3621, Level 0, State 0, Line number 4
The statement has been terminated.

Msg 3621, Level 0, State 0, Line number 5
The statement has been terminated.

Msg 3621, Level 0, State 0, Line number 6
The statement has been terminated.

Msg 3621, Level 0, State 0, Line number 7
The statement has been terminated.

Msg 3621, Level 0, State 0, Line number 8
The statement has been terminated.

Msg 3621, Level 0, State 0, Line number 9
The statement has been terminated.

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dbNewsDictionary]( 
[Id] [int] NOT NULL, 
[Subject] [nvarchar](max) NULL, 
[Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL, 
[MainContent] [nvarchar](max) NULL, 
[SEOsubject] [nvarchar](50) NULL, 
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbNewsDictionary_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
( 
[Id] ASC 
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DU
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the object already exists. Check the destination in order to verify. Did you run your script more than once? That could be part of the problem - you already created the objects. Also, what do you mean by "uploading" your database?